# How to modify the pivot point (center of rotation) for this pygame.draw.line()

Tags: python, pygame

I want to modify from the topLeft from midleft.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
from sys import exit

ALTO_Y_ANCHO_VENTANA = 960,600
COLOR_ROJO = 255,0,0

# ENEMIGO_UNO_SURF I IMPORTED FROM OTHER FOLDER.

# Enemigo_1
enemigo_1_escalado = pygame.transform.scale(enemigo_uno_surf, (80,70)).convert_alpha()
enemigo_1_rect = enemigo_1_escalado.get_rect(midbottom = (66, 530))

while True:

    lista_eventos = pygame.event.get()

    for event in lista_eventos:

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) # tipo Vector2

    centro_enemigo = pygame.math.Vector2(enemigo_1_rect.centerx, enemigo_1_rect.centery) # tipo Vector2

    direction = mouse_pos - centro_enemigo

    length = direction.length()
    scaling_factor = 10000 / length
    endpoint = centro_enemigo + direction * scaling_factor
    
    ###### THIS RECT THAT I WANT TO MODIFY THE PIVOT ########
    draw_line = pygame.draw.line(main_screen, 'Pink', centro_enemigo, endpoint, 2) #linea principal
```

That's because i want the Rect collide whith others. But not like that:[RECT from the Rect of the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHKw4.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the middle right point of the player instead of the center point as the starting point for the beam:

```py
startpoint = pygame.math.Vector2(enemigo_1_rect.midright) 

mouse_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
direction = mouse_pos - startpoint
direction.normalize()

endpoint = startpoint + direction * 10000

pygame.draw.line(main_screen, 'Pink', startpoint, endpoint, 2)
```

---

Note, that the return value of [`pygame.draw.line`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) is a rectangle that bounds the changed pixels, but not a rotated line or rectangle. The bounding rectangle is aligned with the axis of the screen.
If you want to detect the collision of a rectangle with a line you can use [`pygame.Rect.clipline`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clipline), see [How do I check collision between a line and a rect in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56100547/how-do-i-check-collision-between-a-line-and-a-rect-in-pygame/74117346#74117346).
Alternatively, you can also use mask collision detection: [Make a line as a sprite with its own collision in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456195/make-a-line-as-a-sprite-with-its-own-collision-in-pygame/65324946#65324946).